# Making my agent with a difficult name, easier to invoke?

Tags: actions-on-google

I'm creating an agent that interacts with an API I created, Auroras.live. However I always have troubles invoking the test version of the agent from my Google Home.

I really have to stress the "S" in Aurora**s**, and I also have to say "dot", otherwise Google Home interprets it (I think) as Auroras Live, or Aurora.live, without the dot or "S"

This is definitely going to be a problem for others too, as they might not know to pronounce the dot, or forget to stress the "S", and as a result will get frustrated & not use my agent.

While filling out the app details, I tried using different invocations (such as "Talk to Auroras dot live" and "Speak to Aurora Live"), but it wouldn't let me do it, because I needed to use the exact title of my app.

What should I do? Should I (or can I) submit it as an easier to pronounce name (like "the aurora app")? Can I somehow tell Google to accept it with or without the "S" / dot? Any suggestions welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely a case where you would want your invocation name to be (slightly) different than your display name. I would list "Auroras Live" as your display name and "Aurora live" as the invocation name.

As part of the testing instructions, explain the problems you're seeing to the tester and request that both invocations be allowed.

If you want to clearly associate it with the auroras.live website, you could also mention that in the testing instructions (to include the dot), but you should probably also consider including a link to the site from the description and possibly from the action itself.